# Convert from string to double from 4325 to 43.25

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I need help. Device send me temperature and humidity at this format as string:

```
temperature: 4325
humidity: 583
```

I must convert this to double i.e. temp from 4325 to 43.25 and humidity from 583 to 58.3.

I tried to convert to dobble, but it does not work, and I can not find a reasonable solution for now. I can count signs, but it seems to me that there are better solutions than this.

My code

```
string param1=  "4325";
double temperature = double.Parse(param1);
string param2= "583";
double humidity = double.Parse(param2);
```

Comment: Do you *always* divide the temperature by 100 and the humidity by 10? Please show what you've tried and give more details about what went wrong than "it does not work". (I'd probably parse them both as integers and divide by 100.0 and 10.0 respectively.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, could be:

```cs
string temp =  "4325";
double temperature = double.Parse(temp) * 0.01;
string hum = "583";
double humidity = double.Parse(hum) * 0.1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can parse strings for double by using

```cs
if (!double.TryParse(valueString, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dblValue))
{
   // use dblValue if parsing has been successfull
}
```

Comment: if *!* TryParse will never reach your commented line